# Dynamically generate table in loop / foreach MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am writing some very poor code right now and before I even save it I was hoping to get some input on improving it.  I am trying to build an html table with three cells to every row. If the collection has 5 items then that should render as two rows.

The code I have written so far I can see is not very robust and will require constant maintenance but I am unsure of other tools / methods for accomplishing the task.

```
<table>
    @foreach (VideosModel item in Model)
    {
        if (cellCount == 0 || cellCount == 3)
        { 
            @Html.Raw("<tr>") 
        }
           <td style="padding:0px 20px;">
                @item.VideoTitle <br />
                <a href="@item.VideoUrl" target="_blank">
                    <img src="../../.../Video.jpg" /> <br />
                </a>
                @item.VideoDescription
                <br />
            </td>

        cellCount++;

        if (cellCount == 3 || cellCount == 6)
        { 
            @Html.Raw("</tr>") 
        }

        if (cellCount > 3) { cellCount = 0; }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: For starters, there is no need to have the `<tr>` wrapped in an `@Html.Raw()`

Comment: When I don't have it wrapped in the raw I get the error that if then closing brace not found. Such as described here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1654550.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should considering using modulo instead of comparing the values of cellCount to 0, 3 or 6:

```
<table>
    @foreach (VideosModel item in Model)
    {
        if (cellCount % 3 == 0)
        { 
            @:<tr>
        }
           <td style="padding:0px 20px;">
                @item.VideoTitle <br />
                <a href="@item.VideoUrl" target="_blank">
                    <img src="../../.../Video.jpg" />
                </a><br />
                @item.VideoDescription
                <br />
            </td>

        cellCount++;

        if (cellCount % 3 == 0)
        { 
            @:</tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Is the @: shorthand for something? I didn't know about it and Googling @: or MVC @: returns nada.

Comment: Same thing as `<text><tr></text>` http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx