# Dynamic column in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I am using a `foreach` loop, every time it generates a row for a single record. I want to display my 3 records in the first row, next three records in the second row, and so on.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="i-box">
                <div class="i-icon">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "Controller", new { articalName = @item.Id })"><img src="" alt="stack" class="img-fluid"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="i-date">Date</div>
                <h4>HEADER</h4>
                <p>Paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: seems counter % 3 == 0 would do it

Comment: @SandipBantawa Yes thanks for the suggestion ... Used the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506432/dynamically-generate-table-in-loop-foreach-mvc-view`

Comment: Flagged [Dynamically generate table in loop / foreach MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506432/dynamically-generate-table-in-loop-foreach-mvc-view)